# SSL Certificate loading error in postgresql.conf file during restart

Tags: ssl, postgresql, openssl

```
 openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048
 openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
 openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

 chown postgres:postgres server.*
 chmod 0600 server.*
```

but when i run systemctl restart postgresql-15
below error comes. can any one please reply.

```
FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "server.csr": no start line
[2238590] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Looks like you're creating a private key named `root.key` but then creating the certificate using `server.key` which may not exist... and you haven't shown us the config file for postgres where you're specifying the certificate to use.

Comment: postgres is also looking for a csr file rather than the generated crt file; is that what you intended?

Comment: it is typing mistake , the root key has name server.key

Answer (score 0):

`csr` is generally a signing request. This is sent to the CA, and signed. This gives you a certificate.

You almost certainly want to use the certificate, e.g. `server.crt`, not `server.csr`. The signing request can be deleted once it's signed.

Comment: i want to use self-sign certificate which i can use for testing in postgresql.conf file

Comment: @RajeshManiyar please try what I wrote.

Comment: In postgresql.conf file there are 3 parameters 1. ssl_cert_file = server.csr                       2. ssl_key_file=server.key     3. ssl_CA_file=server.crt                are these all three required to be set like these where server.crt is a self sign-certificate created from server.csr

Comment: Still when i restart postgresql service it give error FATAL:  private key file "server.key" has group or world access, DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owne> despite giving above permission of file . it gives same error

Comment: Please change `server.csr` to `server.crt`. You should not use the signing request for anything but getting a signature - which you have done. Furthermore, read the error messages you get. `chmod 0600 server.key; chown postrgresuser server.key` to make key readable only by postgres user.

Comment: even though the file server.key have a permission of rw still it gives same error [root@Primary-Rhel data]# getfacl /var/lib/pgsql/15/data/server.key
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/pgsql/15/data/server.key
# owner: postgres
# group: postgres
user::rw-
group::---
other::---
getting below error.                                                                                                             
 FATAL:  private key file "server.>
 DETAIL:  File must have permission>
 LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: is it may be that file server.key is not load due to pass phrase is set for file ?  i have commented file server.csr but still same error it comes for server.crt and server.key

Comment: Same error message? Did you protect it with a password?